# CakePhp 2.x - plugin model is not being loaded

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, mysql-error-1064

I a making a plugin in CakePhp and I am using multiple models inside the plugin. I created those models by using the console and baked them. I ran into a problem when using 1 of them and it only appears with this specific model.

The model file name:
**GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression.php**

Content of model:

```
<?php
    App::uses('GamificationAppModel', 'Gamification.Model');

    class GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression extends GamificationAppModel {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'oleej';
        exit;
    }

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'GamificationBadgeProgression' => array(
            'className' => 'GamificationBadgeProgression',
            'foreignKey' => 'gamification_badge_progression_id'
        ),
        'GamificationBadgeUnlockAction' => array(
            'className' => 'GamificationBadgeUnlockAction',
            'foreignKey' => 'gamification_badge_unlock_action_id'
        )
    );

    public function addMissingProgression($missingProgression)
    {
        /*$this->saveMany($missingProgression, array(
            'fieldlist' => array('gamification_badge_progression_id', 'gamification_badge_unlock_action_id')
        ));*/
    }
}
```

In the controller of the plugin I have:

```
public $uses = array('Gamification.GamificationBadge',
    'Gamification.GamificationBadgeProgression', 
    'Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockAction',
    'Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression', 
    'Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockType');
```

All the other models are being loaded, except 'Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression'. Which is very weird. It has all required stuff and it follows the naming conventions and everything.
It just isn't being loaded as the constructor is never called and the echo is never shown.

When I call the function from the model like this with an array as parameter:

```
    $this->GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression->addMissingProgression($missingProgression);
```

Then I get an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'addMissingProgression' at line 1
```

Because the model is not loaded.
However CakePhp does create a magic model with the same name, which results in the error above, because the model magically excists but the function ofcourse doesnt and neither do the relations.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you can check weather the model is load or not by `ClassRegistry::isKeySet('Name of your model');`

Comment: It is, because cakephp creates a magical version of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of error is thrown when the Model isn't properly loaded, it tries to execute the method as an SQL function, which obvisouly doesn't exist. At the top of your Controller, check if it has:

```
App::uses('GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression', 'Gamification.Model');
```

That, combined with the `Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression` in the $uses array that you already have should be enough for it to load. If it still fails, as a last resort you could manually load it in your method using a fallback like:

```
if (!is_object($this->GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression)) {
    ClassRegistry::init('Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression');
    $this->GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression = new GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression();
}
```

That would manually load the Model and create an instance for it under `$this->GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression`.

There also appears to be an error in the associations in the model, it should include the Plugin prefixes, like:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'GamificationBadgeProgression' => array(
        'className' => 'Gamification.GamificationBadgeProgression',
        'foreignKey' => 'gamification_badge_progression_id'
    ),
    'GamificationBadgeUnlockAction' => array(
        'className' => 'Gamification.GamificationBadgeUnlockAction',
        'foreignKey' => 'gamification_badge_unlock_action_id'
    )
);
```

Comment: None if it works. And manually loading doesn't work either, because CakePHP creates a magic model with the same name. I can use all default functions like $this->GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression->find('all'), but I cant create my then ofcourse

Comment: Even better, when I try to manually load it as you say, which should work returns an error:  Class 'GamificationBadgeUnlockActionProgression' not found

Comment: @DijkeMark Might have to do with an error I just spotted in your model, it might cause the Model to not load properly because the associations seem off. See my updated answer for fixing that.

Comment: Okay it seems to be working now. Adding the plugin before the class name did the trick. It still is strange, because the other models in the plugin did not need this to get it working